# В англоязычном тексте изменить все окончания слов -ed на окончания -ing

Tags: c

Такую задачку задали в институте, написал код, который изменяет текст, но дело в том, что текст длиной 7 он меняет на текст длиной 8, из-за чего получается эффект склеивания, прошу помощи.

Исходный код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>


#define buffer 300

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "rus");
    int isRandom;
    char text[buffer] = "Education outplayed  giggle d demo roleplay signed  source applyed  denied  declined  carried  lived  strate";
    do {
     printf("Вы желаете ввести текст? (y/n): ");
     switch(getchar()) {
      case 'y': isRandom = 0; break;
      case 'n': isRandom = 1; break;
      default: isRandom = -1;
     }
     fflush(stdin);
    } while(isRandom == -1);
    if(isRandom == 0) {  printf("\nВведите текст: "); fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);}
    printf("\nИсходный текст(Длина: %i):\n", strlen(text));
    puts(text);
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i<strlen(text); i++) if(text[i] != ' ') if(text[i+1] == 'e') if(text[i+2] == 'd') {count++; text[i+1] = 'i'; text[i+2] = 'n'; text[i+3] = 'g';}
    printf("\nНайдено совпадений: %i\n", count);
    printf("\nКонечный результат: \n%s\n\n", text);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Единственное, что я придумал, так это после каждого ed ставить 2 пробела

Comment: Нужен буфер с достаточным количеством места. А потом - "раздвигаем" в нужном месте строку с помощью `memmove` и переписываем...

Comment: @Harry Грубо-говоря я раздвинул, только вот оно потом не хочет переписываться

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проверяй

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define buffer 300

    int main()
    {
        setlocale (LC_ALL, "rus");
        int isRandom;
        char text[buffer] = "Education outplayed giggle d ed dede demo roleplay signed source applyed denied declined carried lived strate";
        do {
         printf("Вы желаете ввести текст? (y/n): ");
         switch(getchar()) {
          case 'y': isRandom = 0; break;
          case 'n': isRandom = 1; break;
          default: isRandom = -1;
         }
         fflush(stdin);
        } while(isRandom == -1);
        if(isRandom == 0) {  printf("\nВведите текст: "); fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin); fflush(stdin);}
        printf("\nИсходный текст(Длина: %i):\n", strlen(text));
        puts(text);
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for(i; i<strlen(text); i++) if(text[i] != ' ') if(text[i+1] == 'e') if(text[i+2] == 'd') if(text[i+3] == ' ') {count++; memmove(&text[i+3], &text[i+2], strlen(text));  text[i+1] = 'i'; text[i+2] = 'n'; text[i+3] = 'g';}
        printf("\nНайдено совпадений: %i\n", count);
        printf("\nКонечный результат: \n%s\n\n", text);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: А это что за бред написан?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Я лишь дополнил код исходного, исходя из того, что ему будет проще в нем разобраться

Comment: А где выделение памяти под результирующую строку, которая должна быть длиннее исходной строки?

Answer (score 1):

Так как заменяющая комбинация символов `"ing"` длиннее заменяемой комбинации символов `"ed"`, то невозможно "на месте" в исходной строке в общем случае произвести такую замену. В исходной строке может быть недостаточно места для выполнения всех таких замен.

Необходимо выделить динамически память под результирующую строку и туда переписать исходную строку с выполнением соответствующих замен.

Для такой задачи лучше написать отдельную функцию, которая будет производить замену одних окончаний слов на другие.

Имеется два подхода. Первый - это когда память под результирующую строку выделяется пользователем функции. Второй подход - это сама функция выделяет необходимую память для результирующей строки.

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа, в которой функция реализована в соответствии со вторым подходом.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * substitute_copy( const char *s, const char *source, const char *dest )
{
    size_t source_n = strlen( source );
    size_t dest_n   = strlen( dest );

    size_t n = 0;

    if ( *source )
    {
        for ( const char *p = s; ( p = strstr( p, source ) ) != NULL; p += source_n )
        {
            n += p != s && 
                 !isspace( ( unsigned char )p[-1] ) && 
                 ( isspace( ( unsigned char )p[source_n] ) || !p[source_n] );
        }
    }       

    char *result = malloc( strlen( s ) + n * ( dest_n - source_n ) + 1 );

    if ( result )
    {
        if ( n == 0 )
        {
            strcpy( result, s );
        }
        else
        {
            const char *p = s, *q = s;
            char *t = result;
            do
            {
                q = strstr( p, source );

                if ( q == NULL )
                {
                    strcpy( t, p );
                }
                else
                {
                    memcpy( t, p, q - p );
                    t += q - p;

                    if ( q != s && 
                         !isspace( ( unsigned char )q[-1] ) &&
                         ( isspace( ( unsigned char )q[source_n] ) || !q[source_n] ) )
                    {
                        strcpy( t, dest );
                        t += dest_n;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strcpy( t, source );
                        t += source_n;
                    }

                    p = q + source_n;
                }
            } while ( q );
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Education outplayed  giggle d demo roleplay signed  "
               "source applyed  denied  declined  carried  lived  strate";

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", s );

    char *p = substitute_copy( s, "ed", "ing" );

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", p );

    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
"Education outplayed  giggle d demo roleplay signed  source applyed  denied  declined  carried  lived  strate"
"Education outplaying  giggle d demo roleplay signing  source applying  deniing  declining  carriing  living  strate"
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88030/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-from-moscow------).